# Why is my pygame screen only displaying a black image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pygame

For some reason even though I have defined everything in the level and level editor I don't get a response. What I really want to do is to display the map on my pygame screen. I am using cv2, sys, cv2_imread, pygame and pygame_locals libraries. No error message is appearing so I did not find any answers on the internet. It also seems to be a problem with the opencv side of code.

Code:

```
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((226, 318))
player_pos = [95, 292]

player = pygame.image.load('Player.png').convert()
player.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))

level1 = list(imread('Map1.png'))  # the​ image

moving_right = False
moving_left = False
moving_up = False
moving_down = False


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    screen.fill((15, 15, 15))

    player_rect = screen.blit(player, player_pos)

    if moving_right == True:
        player_pos[0] += 2
    if moving_left == True:
        player_pos[0] -= 2
    if moving_up == True:
        player_pos[1] -= 2
    if moving_down == True:
        player_pos[1] += 2

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = True
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moving_up = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moving_down = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                player_pos[0] += 24
                moving_right = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                player_pos[0] -= 24
                moving_left = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                player_pos[1] -= 24
                moving_up = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                player_pos[1] += 24
                moving_down = False

    if player_pos[1] > 290:
        moving_down = False #This will be changed later so you die
    if player_pos[1] < 4:
        moving_up = False
    if player_pos[0] < 4:
        moving_left = False
    if player_pos[0] > 212:
        moving_right = False

    a = screen.get_width()/32
    b = screen.get_height()/24

    for i in range(len(level1)):
        for j in range(len(level1[i])):
            blue = list(level1[i][j])[0]
            green = list(level1[i][j])[1]
            red = list(level1[i][j])[2]
            if blue == 255 and green == 255 and red == 255:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(j*a, i *b, 32, 32))
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(j * a, i * b, 32, 32))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
    print(clock.get_fps())

pygame.quit()
```

Player.png:

[image]

Map1.png:

[image: 2]

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `print(blue, green, red)` in that loop? I'd imagine the values aren't what you expect, and you never get to the part that should draw non-black things.

Comment: (Also, I imagine you don't really want to ever draw black tiles, since you're already filling the screen with a non-black color and drawing the player sprite...)

Comment: The background is black and white and the player does not have any black or white in any of its pixels. I want to make the player collide with the map

Comment: Minor tweak that may be worth trying: change `pygame.display.update()` to `pygame.display.flip()`.

Comment: It did not work but thanks anyways

Comment: One more thought, try changing `(0, 0, 0)` to `(0, 0, 100)` or something other than black in  the else statement of `pygame.draw.rect(...)`.  It's possibe you are updating the screen, just you're always adding a black rectangle.  If so, this should help narrow your search for the bug.

Comment: Thanks for the info but it does not work ether and i cant narrow it down to any visible problem.

Comment: Is it possible to share `Player.png`? Or you do not want to share?

Comment: It is just a really simple sprite but ok

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. No one can debug this without it; they can only guess their way forward, which is slow and mostly inaccurate. Remove everything that doesn't contribute to the problem and make sure everything is defined so we can run the example our self (for example, define or replace `imread` with something equivalent).

Comment: We don't have the level map so it is hard to know as we don't know what is in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot solve the whole problem, but one of the  main reason you get black screen is because you multiply `j*a` and `b*i`.

For instance, if you try:

```
if blue == 255 and green == 255 and red == 255:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), pygame.Rect(j, i, 32, 32))
else:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0, pygame.Rect(j, i, 32, 32))
```

and if you set coordinate to, let's say 100 you will see the player as well:

```
if blue == 255 and green == 255 and red == 255:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), pygame.Rect(100, 100, 32, 32))
else:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0, pygame.Rect(100, 100, 32, 32))
```

**as a result, please double check `pygame.Rect(j*a, b*i, 32, 32)`. I do not know exactly what you want to do. But I think this will help you.**

the full code for j, i;

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame import *
import cv2

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((226, 318))
player_pos = [95, 292]

player = pygame.image.load('Player.png').convert()
player.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))

level1 = list(cv2.imread('Map1.png'))  # the​ image

moving_right = False
moving_left = False
moving_up = False
moving_down = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    screen.fill((15, 15, 15))
    player_rect = screen.blit(player, player_pos)
    if moving_right == True:
        player_pos[0] += 2
    if moving_left == True:
        player_pos[0] -= 2
    if moving_up == True:
        player_pos[1] -= 2
    if moving_down == True:
        player_pos[1] += 2
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = True
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moving_up = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moving_down = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                player_pos[0] += 24
                moving_right = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                player_pos[0] -= 24
                moving_left = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                player_pos[1] -= 24
                moving_up = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                player_pos[1] += 24
                moving_down = False
    if player_pos[1] > 290:
        moving_down = False #This will be changed later so you die
    if player_pos[1] < 4:
        moving_up = False
    if player_pos[0] < 4:
        moving_left = False
    if player_pos[0] > 212:
        moving_right = False
    a = screen.get_width()/32
    b = screen.get_height()/24
    print(a, b)
    for i in range(len(level1)):
        for j in range(len(level1[i])):
            blue = list(level1[i][j])[0]
            green = list(level1[i][j])[1]
            red = list(level1[i][j])[2]
            if blue == 255 and green == 255 and red == 255:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), pygame.Rect(j, i, 32, 32))
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), pygame.Rect(j, i, 32, 32))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
    print(clock.get_fps())

pygame.quit()
```

the full code for j = 100, i = 100;

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame import *
import cv2

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((226, 318))
player_pos = [95, 292]

player = pygame.image.load('Player.png').convert()
player.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))

level1 = list(cv2.imread('Map1.png'))  # the​ image

moving_right = False
moving_left = False
moving_up = False
moving_down = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    screen.fill((15, 15, 15))
    player_rect = screen.blit(player, player_pos)
    if moving_right == True:
        player_pos[0] += 2
    if moving_left == True:
        player_pos[0] -= 2
    if moving_up == True:
        player_pos[1] -= 2
    if moving_down == True:
        player_pos[1] += 2
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = True
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moving_up = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moving_down = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                player_pos[0] += 24
                moving_right = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                player_pos[0] -= 24
                moving_left = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                player_pos[1] -= 24
                moving_up = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                player_pos[1] += 24
                moving_down = False
    if player_pos[1] > 290:
        moving_down = False #This will be changed later so you die
    if player_pos[1] < 4:
        moving_up = False
    if player_pos[0] < 4:
        moving_left = False
    if player_pos[0] > 212:
        moving_right = False
    a = screen.get_width()/32
    b = screen.get_height()/24
    print(a, b)
    for i in range(len(level1)):
        for j in range(len(level1[i])):
            blue = list(level1[i][j])[0]
            green = list(level1[i][j])[1]
            red = list(level1[i][j])[2]
            if blue == 255 and green == 255 and red == 255:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), pygame.Rect(100, 100, 32, 32))
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), pygame.Rect(100, 100, 32, 32))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
    print(clock.get_fps())

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much